# Is the "Check Availability" link on Activities an option for custom objects?

Tags: activities, calendar

There's a link on Activities next to the start datetime that says 'check availability' and it links to the day and time in the calendar.

I'm wondering if this is an option somewhere else that I can use for other date fields, or if this is just standard for Activities exclusively...

I tried Googling this, and couldn't tell if this is actually a built-in standard thing, or just something somebody else in this org developed, but it doesn't seem to be custom in any way so hopefully this is a standard thing and my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature on Events that checks availability is one of those object-unique features. You can write your own code to handle this for other objects, but you can't just take the out-of-the-box feature and apply it to any arbitrary object. There are several apps on the AppExchange that do availability with their own custom objects (e.g. a time management tool that shows availability), but I don't know of one that just specifically gives you the ability to configure any arbitrary object.